# Sharepoint 2010 FAST Search is not indexing the URL

Tags: fast-search, fast

I am using SharePoint FAST search 2010. I am having two page libraries in a site. I am able to see the content in the search results from one of the Page library aspx page. But, I am unable to see the content from the other page library. I have configured the search availablity to index all the web parts in the page. But the page libraries are having the same set of permissions and published the major versions.

Comment: Check if versioning is enabled on the second library and all documents are in Published/Approved status

Comment: Yes. it is enabled and published the major versions for both the libraries.

Comment: Search uses a service account. Check whether that account has permission on the library.

Comment: Yes.It is having full rights for the library and Defult content Access Account.

Comment: If you go to the crawl log in the SSA, can you find entries for the missing library?

Comment: Sorry. Both the libraries has crawled correctly.And I dont see any entry for the non-working library.

Comment: So you see an entrymfor the non-working lib, but no entry for the items in it? Is that correct?